# Double modulus operator

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, pseudocode, modulus

I know exactly how does a single modulus work. Does double modulus work the same? And assuming we have this pseudocode

```
j<-0
n<-10
for(j in 1:n)
{ if(!j%%2) 
    {
      next
     }
   print(j)
}
```

What does the 'if' condition mean and what is the output of this code?

My solution is: If J is not divisible by 2 increase J, Otherwise, print J. And the overall code outputs even numbers from (1-10). Is this solution correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%%` operators is, as far as I know, not "standard" enough to be able to use it unambiguously in pseudocode without accompanying explanation of what it is supposed to be.

This snippet appears to be R code though, and in R the `%%` operator does mean remainder (with the sign of the divisor).

But since there is a `!` (logical-not) too, the code will be printing *odd* numbers, since it's skipping the even numbers.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.But if next is the skipping line, doesn't it mean that it is skipping odd numbers (since if condition is true of odd numbers)?

Comment: @user91 the condition is true for even numbers, thanks to the not-operator